# JOIN error & Prepend custom description with JQ

Tags: jq

The command I run produces the JSON output other fields

```
{
  "description": "Test A",
  "planned_start": "2023-11-13T06:00:00Z",
  "planned_end": "2023-11-20T08:00:00Z",
  "priority": "low",
  ....
}
{
  "description": "Test B",
  "planned_start": "2023-11-13T06:00:00Z",
  "planned_end": "2023-11-20T06:00:00Z",
  "priority": "medium",
  ....
}
{
  "description": "Test C",
  "planned_start": "2023-11-13T06:00:00Z",
  "planned_end": "2023-11-20T06:00:00Z",
  "priority": "high",
  ....
}
```

I have run the following command to select the fields I want. Trying to find how get the following output.

```
command | jq -r '.[] | select (
  (.priority == "low") or (.priority == "high") or (.priority == "moderate")
)
| [.description, .planned_start, .planned_end]'
```

which produces

```
[
 "Test A",
  "2023-11-13T06:00:00Z",
  "2023-11-20T06:00:00Z",
]
[
  "Test B",
  "2023-11-13T06:00:00Z",
  "2023-11-20T06:00:00Z",
]
[
  "Test C",
  "2023-11-13T06:00:00Z",
  "2023-11-20T06:00:00Z",
]
```

If I add the join,

```
command | jq -r '.[] | select (
  (.priority == "low") or (.priority == "high") or (.priority == "moderate")
)
| [.description, .planned_start, .planned_end | join(",")]'
```

I am getting an error

> Cannot iterate over string ("Test A")

Q1: How to fix the error
Q2: How do I prepend my own header to each value to get the following output

```
"Description": "Test A", "Start": "2023-11-13T06:00:00Z", "End": "2023-11-20T08:00:00Z"
"Description": "Test B", "Start": "2023-11-13T06:00:00Z", "End": "2023-11-20T06:00:00Z"
"Description": "Test C", "Start": "2023-11-13T06:00:00Z", "End": "2023-11-20T06:00:00Z"
```

Comment: Q1: You're using `| join(",")` in the wrong place. Move it outside the array constructor: `…] | join(",")`. Regarding Q2: Please elaborate on your output format, as it's not JSON anymore (missing curly braces). Do you want to produce a long string as shown including JSON-like field names, or do want proper JSON objects each compacted to a single line? For both cases, constructing your last array isn't really helping.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Moving join outside the array  produced the output I want. For the 2nd question I want to add my own labels to the output and proper JSON objects compacted into each line

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Q1:

You're using `| join(",")` in the wrong place. It expects an array but by being inside the array constructor, you provide it with the array's values, i.e. strings (hence the error message `Cannot iterate over string ("Test A")`). Move it outside the array constructor, and it'll work:

```bash
… | [.description, .planned_start, .planned_end] | join(",")
```

---

Regarding Q2:

> I want to add my own labels to the output and proper JSON objects compacted into each line

Instead of constructing an array of values, construct an object and name your fields as you see fit. Then, use the `-c` flag to output each object on izs own line:

```bash
… | jq -c '.[] | select(IN(.priority; "low", "high", "moderate"))
| {Description: .description, Start: .planned_start, End: .planned_end}'
```

Note: I have also simplified your `select` condition from multiple `or`s to a single `IN` using a stream of values. If you're on jq < 1.6, use `select(any(.priority = ("low", "high", "moderate"); .))` instead.

Comment: Your suggestion of select produced what I asked. One more question:  Is it possible to get a JSON array so the output is 
[ {"Description": "Test A", "Start": "xxxx", "End": "xxx"}, { ... }, { ....}]

Comment: @ChenuluPeri Sure, don't destructure the array in the first place (you did it with `.[] | …`). Instead, do everything using `map(…)`, i.e. `map(select(…) | {Description: .description, …})`. With an array as the result, however, you don't have a stream of objects anymore, just that one item (the array), so the `-c` flag would put all of it in one line. Use it, if this is what you want, or drop the flag to get regular pretty-printed JSON.

Answer (score 0):

To get your desired output, you'd just iterate through the list of objects and output the properties you want.

Since the input appears to be streamed in, you *don't* want to use `.[]` at the start to expand, you're iterating over the values of the objects at that point. You'd only need that if your input is an array. This is likely the cause for the error you see in Q1.

To start, pick out the properties you want to output. Since you want to give them a different "header", you can map it out to an object. Then you can use `to_entries/0` to convert the object to key/value pairs and map each pair to how you wanted to present it. Since you want the keys and values quoted strings, you could use `tojson` to have them quoted. With the array of strings you want to output, you  could then join that array.

```
$ command | jq -r '
select(.priority == ("low", "high", "moderate"))
  | { Description: .description, Start: .planned_start, End: .planned_end }
  | to_entries
  | map("\(.key|tojson): \(.value|tojson)")
  | join(", ")
'
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/UEN1dQJONhn)